# C# Image processing: Image similarity

Tags: c#, database, image-processing, comparison

I was wondering if you would be kind enough to tell me if what I am attempting is Possible and which image processing library would be best suited to the task.

I am programming a web application in c # and i wish to compare an object in an uploaded image to the images stored in a mysql database and arrive to the closest match.

For Example:
The user uploads an image of a mobile phone, crops the image to focus mainly on the mobile phone. Now I have loads of images in the database and I would like to compare the user's cropped image to find a matching image in the database that contains a similar (close match) mobile phone.

I was thinking:
1) Object detection in user's uploaded image
2) Segment the images from the database and find carry out similarity tests.

This is just ideas and I was wondering if you might be able to guide me as to what library to use and which features.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar requirement in our winforms demo. We tried some toolkits and ended up using a commercial toolkit named leadtools. They have correlation functions that can compare images with all the areas of the same dimensions in another image. For more information, see this link:
http://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v175/dh/po/leadtools.imageprocessing.core~leadtools.imageprocessing.core.correlationcommand.html

Answer (score 2):

Use [SURF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speeded_up_robust_features), I am pretty sure that Google uses this for [goggles](http://www.google.com/mobile/goggles/#text)

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into the surf documentation. I'm hopping that it's something that can be easily programmed using C#. The Google goggles actually does what I am trying to do on a much larger and professional scale.

Answer (score 1):

The recognition of a small subset of objects such as barcodes, peoples, faces is hard enough - but to automate the recognition of an arbitrary set of objects is even harder. Certainly not the subject for an image processing beginner! If you really need this functionality, I would recommend buying software for this task:

A quick Google search finds:

- [XLab Object detection software](http://research.xlab.si/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=182&Itemid=173)